# Reduce multiple transparent colored layers into one in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, layers

I purchased an Adobe stock vector image that is made of multiple layers that are laid over with transparency to get the color darker etc — as seen below. How do I reduce in Illustrator multiple layers that are creating a different color through transparency into one Layer with the color created? If I use Pathfinder it just splits the layers but does not reduced it into one. Is it even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "layers"... What you see in the Layers panel in Illustrator is actually layers *and objects*, so probably not; all of those shapes *need* to be separate objects.

As for reducing the transparency down you can do that. Just go to:

*Object → Flatten Transparency...*

That'll flatten all the transparencies, blending modes and colors to what you see so all you'll have left are solid colored shapes, rather than blending transparent shapes.